# Will Sector-Administrated planets ever upgrade their Colony Ship?

Tags: stellaris

I threw one of my colonial planets into a sector in a recent spat of colonizing, since I needed more, newer, planets in my cores!

Today, I looked back at it, and... well...

[image]

Plenty more than 5 pop, and still rockin' that Reassembled Ship Shelter.

Since upgrading costs influence, is it even possible for sectors to upgrade this themselves?

Comment: Did the sector have enough minerals for the upgrade?

Comment: I was reading [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellaris/comments/4jmt0t/sectors_101_here_are_some_tips_to_make_using/) and it looks like you have to make sure your sector has the resources to Upgrade. A big problem for most people is they have outposts in their sector which takes up the sector's influence gain, which means they never upgrade the ship shelter. Sectors appear to build all food buildings until max population, then will rebuild and fully upgrade one building at a time. So make sure they have resources to upgrade and give them a bit of time, and they'll get there!

Comment: @Rachel Don't think so - there's a lot of confusion in that thread (including linking back to this post!). That poster seems to be referring to be referring to conquered sectors with Empire-Capital Complexes (The only regular building that generates influence).

Comment: Given that I have personally seen a sector without either an Empire-Capital Complex (for positive Influence gain) and without any frontier outposts (for negative Influence gain) that still managed to upgrade its buildings, Sectors must either passively generate influence (and *not* display this on the sector summary screen, like it does for conquered Empire-Complxes), or ignore the Influence cost entirely (which is the Occam's Razor of things).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like, eventually... yes!
[image]

Couldn't tell ya what triggers it, though.

Additionally, I found this line in the `00_strategic_resources` script file:

```
influence = {
    accumulative = yes
    AI_category = influence
    max = 1000
    sector_ignore_cost = yes
}
```

Which seems to explain how Sectors handle the influence cost (They ignore it! Those cheaters!)

And, confirmed by Paradox Developer:
https://twitter.com/Martin_Anward/status/737198287254654976

> Sectors do not have influence, they ignore influence costs when building. Outposts cost for country in Clarke.

Comment: Haha, cheating AI. But could you explain what influence cost is?

Comment: @Tom Influence is the Purple stockpile-able resource, compared to Yellow energy and Red minerals.